# Can I use an SVG <use> tag with an external reference in either a Data URI or via createObjectURL?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

This works on html page:

```
<svg><use xlink:href="assets/markers.svg#MarkerType_Admin" /></svg>
```

This does not work

```
<img href="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='assets/markers.svg%23MarkerType_Admin' /%3E%3C/svg%3E" />
```

This does not work either:

```
const temp = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<use xlink:href="http://localhost:49374/assets/markers.svg#MarkerType_Center" /></svg>`;
const blob = new Blob([temp], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
myImageElement.href= URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Do external references only work when you are using SVG DOM elements?

Comment: <img> contents cannot be external. <img> <image> and background-image must all be self-contained